# FullCalendar : Ignore events during select

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I've created a monthly calendar using fullCalendar [month view](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.4.0/demos/selectable.html).

On my calendar, I've displayed only one event per day. This event is used to display user's status (available, not available, busy...)

Because I'll always have 1 event per day, I've set `eventLimit` to true to avoid multiple events and because this event is about the entire day, I've also set `editable` to false to prevent events' drag & drop .

Here is my code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: false, // Prevent event drag & drop
    events: '/json/calendar', // Get all events using a json feed
    selectable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // Only 1 event per day
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today'
    },
    select: function(start, end) {
        window.location.hash = '#oModal-calendar'; // Display some popup with a form
        end.subtract(1, 'days');
        $('#checkboxButton').data('start', start);
        $('#checkboxButton').data('end', end);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    }
});
```

I want my user to be able to select days directly from the calendar so I've set `selectable: true` in the calendar's option. However, I've got many feedback that "it didn't worked".
After some investigation, I found that users often click on the event block instead of the day.
Because events are draggable by default, a click on an event doesn't trigger the select and because I've set `editable` to false it doesn't do anything anymore.
This combination leads my users to think that there is a bug.

---

I would like the fullCalendar select to work like there was no event on the calendar. How can I achieve this behavior ?

Edit: here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ure8yrcp/) based on full calendar example and my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

FullCalendar event's click is bind to the css class `fc-day-grid-event`.

It's possible to simply ignore it with one css line `pointer-events: none;`.

```
.fc-day-grid-event {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here is the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ure8yrcp/3/) updated.

Comment: I spent hours digging into the JS trying to figure out how to handle this. Tried all kinds of proposed solutions and plenty of my own hacky attempts. This is all it took... Thank you (6 years later)!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to allow the user to click on event's through the `eventClick` callback, but when they click on them trigger the "select" function through FullCalendar's API `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('select', start, end)`.

I updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8v02tym3/1/) example with the relevant code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: false, // Prevent event drag & drop
    defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
    events: [{
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2015-02-01'
    }, {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2015-02-12T12:00:00'
    }],
    selectable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // Only 1 event per day
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today'
    },

    select: function (start, end) {
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
        var eventData;
        if (title) {
            eventData = {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end
            };
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
        }
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        var start = calEvent.start;
        var end = calEvent.end;
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('select', start, end);
    }
});
```

Comment: While it works for a simple click, you cannot click on an event and drag your mouse to select multiple days at once. I really want to "ignore events".

Comment: I see. There is nothing in FullCalendar's  documentation that seems to help for that issue. Why not just change the cursor to "cursor: no-drop;" so the user knows not to click on the event data? Or make the event less intrusive, so the user does not think to click on it?